# Update Button Status in ListView Loading

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing an App in which i am showing status of list view item, here: I am showing SD Card Images, and allowing user click on Upload button to upload image to server, and showing result as well, like: If upload completes to server then showing Upload Complete and if user already uploaded to server then showing Already Uploaded but whenever user do click on Upload button, but now i want to show the status of an image, whenever List Loads, please see below screen shot:

[image]

**UploadActivity.java:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);

         // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }           

        // click to create new event
        btn_previous_activity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_previous_activity);
        btn_previous_activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // using Intent to call EventListActivity               
                Intent intentNewEvent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, EventListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentNewEvent);
            }
        });

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();
        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "getSD() :::--- " + ImageList);

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }


    private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();

        String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyNewImages/";
        File f = new File (string+ SingleAngelActivity.customFolder+ "/");

        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "KEY_TITLE :::--- " + f);
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();
        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "getListImages() :::--- " + files);

        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)           
        {
            File  file = files[i];
            Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "i<files.length() :::--- " + i);
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "List <String> it :::--- " + it);
        return it;
    }

//Upload
    public void startUpload(final int position) {      
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                        // Show ProgressBar
                        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //  Status  
                        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                        status.setText("Uploading..");

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                    }
                }); 
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }


    // Async Upload
    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String resServer;
        int position;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int resCode = 0;
            String resMessage = "";

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";

            //  File Path
            String strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Upload to PHP Script
            String strUrlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/res/files.php";              

            try {
                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                if(!file.exists())
                {
                    resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                    return null;
                }

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);  
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                        .getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                        + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Response Code and  Message
                resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(read);
                    }
                    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                    bos.close();

                    resMessage = new String(result);
                }

                Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                resServer = resMessage.toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Exception handling
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
        }       
    }

    // when upload finish
    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {

        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        // Show ProgressBar
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // Status
        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strMessage = "File Exists!";

        try {      

            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strMessage = c.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Prepare Status       
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {               
            status.setText( strMessage );
            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // Enabled Button again
            Button btnUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setText("Already Uploaded");
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            status.setText("Upload Completed.");
            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: off topic comment: `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);` <= i love this :)

Comment: can you please post code of ImageAdapter?